# Video iframes not showing up in Wordpress 3.8 site

Tags: wordpress, iframe, video

When I insert iframe code for either a Vimeo or YouTube featured video in my Wordpress 3.8 site, the videos show up for a second and then disappear. Here is the homepage that should have a featured video loading under the navbar: http://www.expertgeneralist.com/afad2. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

The videos are appearing just fine for me in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE10 on Mac. Have you been able to resolve the issue?